# WCF Service, how do I tell if I am publishing WSDL or MEX?

Tags: wcf, wsdl, mex

It's my understanding that MEX and WSDL are two different ways of publishing metadata. In the interest of letting clients choose the one they prefer, I'd like to enable both. But I'm not entirely sure how.

My webconfig simply contains:

`<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />`

and when browsing to it shows that default page, with a link to serviceblahblah?wsdl which suggests I am publishing just the WSDL.

My question is, is this using MEX, if not how can I also publish MEX, and should I be publishing both?

I'm using the basichttpsbinding if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and when browsing to it shows that default page, with a link to serviceblahblah?wsdl which suggests I am publishing just the WSDL.

No, you are just *visiting* the WSDL. What else do you expect to see on that URL? ;-)

The [`httpGetEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgetenabled.aspx) attribute enables the publishing of WSDL metadata. As shown in the [`mexHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967390.aspx) documentation and [Getting Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751519.aspx), if you want to expose MEX, you also have to expose a MEX endpoint you can then access:

```
<!-- the mex endpoint is explosed[sic] at         
http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->

<endpoint address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Clients, when discovering your service, will try to call the `/mex` endpoint first. If not found, they will request the WSDL. You can see this using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) when you click "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio and input the plain service URL, and I'm sure this behaviour documented somewhere.

Comment: Great, that makes it much clearer. Would you recommend publishing a MEX endpoint too?

Comment: @SLC yes, (in short): MEX can expose more detailed metadata than WSDL.